# SQL computing and reusing fiscal year calculation in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a condition in my SQL query, using Oracle 11g database,  that depends on a plan starting or ending with in a fiscal year:

```
(BUSPLAN.START_DATE BETWEEN (:YEAR || '-04-01') AND (:YEAR+1 || '-03-31')) OR
(BUSPLAN.END_DATE BETWEEN (:YEAR || '-04-01') AND (:YEAR+1 || '-03-31'))
```

For now, I am passing in YEAR as a parameter.  It can be computed as (pseudocode):

```
IF CURRENT MONTH IN (JAN, FEB, MAR):
    USE CURRENT YEAR // e.g. 2015
ELSE:
    USE CURRENT YEAR + 1  // e.g. 2016
```

Is there a way I could computer the `:YEAR` parameter within in an SQL query and reuse it  for the `:YEAR` parameter?

Comment: This is easy to do with a CTE -- do you need an example

Comment: @Hogan yes, please, I'm not sure how to use CTE

Comment: Your logic seems to be If current year is 2015, and current month is one of Jan, Feb, Mar than  fiscal year of `2015-04-01` through `2016-03-31`? And if current year is 2015 and month is greater than Mar, you want `2016-04-01` through `2017-03-31`? Or the **next** fiscal year. is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTEs are easy, you can make little tables on the fly.  With a 1 row table you just cross join it and then you have that value available every row:

```
WITH getyear as
(
   SELECT
      CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'mm') in ('01','02','03') THEN 
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)
           ELSE 
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) + 1
      END as ynum from dual
), mydates as
(
  SELECT getyear.ynum || '-04-01' as startdate,
         getyear.ynum+1 || '-03-31' as enddate
  from getyear
)
select 
  -- your code here
from BUSPLAN, mydates -- this is a cross join
where 
  (BUSPLAN.START_DATE BETWEEN mydates.startdate AND mydates.enddate) OR
  (BUSPLAN.END_DATE BETWEEN  mydates.startdate AND mydates.enddate)
```

note, values statement is probably better if Oracle has values then the first CTE would look like this:

```
VALUES(CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'mm') in ('01','02','03') THEN 
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)
           ELSE 
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) + 1)
```

> I don't have access to Oracle so I might have bugs typos etc since I didn't test.

Comment: Thanks, works beautifully.  I made a very minor change to check `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) > 3` in `getyear` case statement

Comment: @dave - I actually thought about doing it that way but figured if you had more cases this way would be easier to convert to the general case.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you shared there is a problem and a potential problem.

**Problem, implicit conversion to date without format string.**

In `(BUSPLAN.START_DATE BETWEEN (:YEAR || '-04-01') AND (:YEAR+1 || '-03-31'))` two strings are being formed and then converted to dates. The conversion to date is going to change depending on the value of NLS_DATE_FORMAT. To insure that the string is converted correctly `to_date(:YEAR || '-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

**Potential problem, boundary at the end of the year when time <> midnight.**

Oracle's `date` type holds both date and time. A test like `someDate between startDate and endDate` will miss all records that happened after midnight on endDate. One simple fix that precludes use of indexes on `someDate` is `trunc(someDate) between startDate and endDate`.

A more general approach is to define date ranges and closed open intervals. `lowerBound <= aDate < upperBound` where `lowerBound is the same as`startDate`above and`upperBound`is`endDate` plus one day.

*Note:* Some applications used Oracle date columns as dates and always store midnight, if your application is of that sort, then this is not a problem. And check constraints like `check (trunc(dateColumn) = dateColumn)` would make sure it stays that way.

---

**And now, to answer the question actually asked.**

Using subquery factoring (Oracle's terminology) / common table expression (SQL Server's terminology) one can avoid repetition within a query.

Instead of figuring out the proper year, and then using strings to put together dates, the code below starts by getting January 1 at Midnight of the current calendar year, `trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR'))`. Then it adds an offset in months. When the months are Jan, Feb, Mar, the current fiscal year started last year on 4/1, or nine months before the start of this year. The offset is -9. Else the current fiscal year started 4/1 of this calendar year, start of this year plus three months.

Instead of end date, an upper bound is calculated, similar to lower bound, but with the offsets being 12 greater than lower bound to get 4/1 the following year.

```
with current_fiscal_year as (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')
            , case when extract(month from sysdate) <= 3 then -9 else 3 end) as LowerBound
        , add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')
            , case when extract(month from sysdate) <= 3 then 3 else 15 end) as UpperBound
    from dual)
select *
from busplan
cross join current_fiscal_year CFY
where (CFY.LowerBound <= busplan.start_date and busplan.start_date < CFY.UpperBound)
or (CFY.LowerBound <= busplan.end_date and busplan.end_date < CFY.UpperBound)
```

---

**And yet more unsolicited advise.**

The times I've had to deal with fiscal year stuff, avoiding repetition within a query was low hanging fruit. Having the fiscal year calculations consistent and correct among many queries, that was the essence of the work. So I'd recommend a developing PL/SQL package that centralizes fiscal calculations. It might include a function like:

```
create or replace function GetFiscalYearStart(v_Date in date default sysdate) 
    return date 
as begin
    return add_months(trunc(v_Date, 'YEAR')
        , case when extract(month from v_Date) <= 3 then -9 else 3 end);
end GetFiscalYearStart;
```

Then the query above becomes:

```
select *
from busplan
where (GetFiscalYearStart() <= busplan.start_date 
    and busplan.start_date < add_months(GetFiscalYearStart(), 12))
or (GetFiscalYearStart() <= busplan.end_date 
    and busplan.end_date < add_months(GetFiscalYearStart(), 12))
```

Comment: I don't agree with the use of functions -- most sql optimizers are much happier with repeated sections of a query over function to create optimized versions.

Comment: @Hogan Depends on the function and the query.

Comment: Really? You sure? I've never seen (or can think of) a case where a function "reducing repetition" would make a query faster.  I know (and have used) faster functions when they were call-outs to compiled libraries which providing functionality not available in SQL or libraries optimized for specialized functionality (most often parsing or pattern matching).  But just some standard SQL like a case statement or a truncate?  I'm having a hard time believing that.  I look forward to an example proving me wrong. Just saying "depends" is not enough -- prove it.

Comment: @Hogan I think we are misunderstanding each other. I've seen functions that do massive damage to performance. And functions where any performance hit is noise. I've not claimed that functions are faster than copying their implementation into every query that needs them. Just more likely to be correct then copy paste develop. And no, I'm not going to try to fit a performance demo into the comments of an unrelated question.